# Insert post data as array from grid in database by codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to insert data by grid where data can be in 1 row or in multiple rows. I want to do this with an array in codeigniter. The problem is I can't insert this code in my data base by my code. There is code presentation of what I'm doing. I want to insert multiple rows in database by grid and I am receiving data in post as an array I can't insert data.

```
    <?php 
     $n = $m; // (could be any number to nth level);
     for($i=0; $i<=$n; $i++) { 
     ?> 
    <tr><td><input name="field1[]" id="active[]" value="" /></td> 
    <td><input name="field2[]" id="active[]" value="" />
    </td> <td><input name="field3[]" id="active[]" value="" />
    </td> </tr> 
    <?php }

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['field1']); $i++) {

   $data = array(
   'field1' => $_POST['field1'][$i],
   'field2' => $_POST['field2'][$i], 
   'field3' => $_POST['field3'][$i], 
   'field4' => $_POST['field4'][$i], );
   if ($_POST['field'][$i] = '') {
   $this->db->insert('field_table', $data);  
    } 
   ?>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so its your view

```
 <tr><td><input name="field1[]" id="active[]" value="" /></td> 
  <td><input name="field2[]" id="active[]" value="" />
  </td> <td><input name="field3[]" id="active[]" value="" />
```

now in the controller you need to get all three arrays as

```
$a=$_POST['field1'];
$b=$_POST['field2'];
$c=$_POST['field3'];

    $i = new MultipleIterator();
    $i->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($a), 'field1');
    $i->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($b), 'field2');
    $i->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($v), 'field3');
```

then its simple

```
foreach ($i as $item) {

        $dr = $item[0];
        $tl = $item[1];
        $li = $item[2];
   $data = array(
   'field1' => $dr,
   'field2' => $tl, 
   'field3' =>$li
 );
   if ($_POST['field'][$i] = '') {
   $this->db->insert('field_table', $data);  
    }
 }
```

bingo